# Name is not displaying with a capitalalize letter on the show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make sure that when someone is creating an account, their first and last names are capitalized so that their last name shows up as `Bob` vs `bob`. I have been using the following in the user controller.

```
.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
.capitalize
.titleize
```

In `binding.pry`, it is being capitalized just after using `capitalize` method. However, when the info is displayed on the show page, it is lower case.

This is my code in my controller:

```
full_name_upcase =
@ambassador.first_name.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ') + ' ' +
@ambassador.last_name.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
@ambassador.full_name = full_name_upcase
```

And this is my call on the show page:

```
<h3><%= ambassador.full_name %></h3>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I think I need to capitalize the name in a different place.

Comment: why are you using `ambassador` rather than  `@ambassador` for `<h3><%= ambassador.full_name %></h3>`?

Comment: you should use `@ambassador.save` in your controller， persistent attribute to database.

Comment: How do you want to handle names like *Rafael van der Vaart*? Your rule how to capitalize names is way too simple. I suggest to read: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: so many answers and no correct one? dude, thats not what we like @stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 2):

You could add a method on the `User` model:

```
# app/models/user.rb  
def full_name
  "#{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}"
end
```

This is assuming you have `first_name` and `last_name` attributes on your `User` model.

Then in your view you could do something like:

```
# app/views/users/show.html.erb
<h3><%= @ambassador.full_name %></h3>
```

The model is the best place for methods like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to store capitalized names in the database (in such a case @pangpang’s comment is to be applied), and keeping @mudasobwa's view in mind. I would prefer to do it this way:

in your `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  def full_name
    read_attribute(:full_name) && read_attribute(:full_name).split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
  end
end
```

This would not override the value in your database, and will moreover provide you the capitalize format everywhere without creating any different instance_variable/method to access that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to store capitalized names in the database (in such a case @pangpang’s comment is to be applied,) you should introduce another instance variable:

```
@full_name_upcase = @ambassador........
```

and later in the view:

```
<h3><%= @full_name_upcase %></h3>
```

Instance variables are being passed to view.

But the best option would be to introduce a helper method for this:

```
def capitalized
  full_name.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end
```

and in the view:

```
<h3><%= @ambassador.capitalize %></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want to persistent attribute(full_name) to database, you should use `@ambassador` in view.

```
<h3><%= @ambassador.full_name %></h3>
```

or you have to save your change:

```
full_name_upcase =
@ambassador.first_name.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ') + ' ' +
@ambassador.last_name.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
@ambassador.full_name = full_name_upcase
@ambassador.save
```

Comment: OP never said that capitalized value is to be stored into database, besides being displayed properly.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes, I didn't said he must do like this, he can do if he want

Answer (score 0):

why did nobody came up with the idea to have nice data inside the database?

```
class User
  before_validation {
    self.firstname.capitalize!
    self.lastname.capitalize!
  }

  validate :capital_names

  def full_name
    "#{firstname} #{lastname}"
  end

  private

    def capital_names
      #should never throw!
      errors.add :firstname, "needs to be capitalized" if firstname != firstname.capitalize
      errors.add :lastname, "needs to be capitalized" if lastname != lastname.capitalize
    end
end
```